# How can the jib maven plugin authenticate to docker hub and publish to ECR?

Tags: bamboo, docker-registry, jib

I've been using the [jib-maven-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin) to build docker tarball images from a bamboo container instance which is then pushed to an ECR.

I have the following server instance in `~/.m2/settings.xml` which resides in the builder image:

```
<server>
  <id>registry.hub.docker.com</id>
  <username>${docker.hub.username}</username>
  <password>${docker.hub.password}</password>
</server>
```

This I then call with maven:

```
mvn -Ddocker.hub.username=${bamboo.docker_hub_username} \
    -Ddocker.hub.password=${bamboo.docker_hub_password} \
    package deploy
```

where deploy is associated with the `buildTar` jib execution goal.

This however does not seem to use my account when pulling images from dockerhub which I need for amazoncoretto.

I recieve the following error from jib.

```
Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.6.0:buildTar (docker-package) on project auth-server: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "TOOMANYREQUESTS",
      "message": "You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround by utilising the jib `jib.from.auth.username` and `jib.from.auth.password` system parameters.

```
mvn -Djib.from.auth.username=${bamboo.docker_hub_username} \
    -Djib.from.auth.password=${bamboo.docker_hub_password} \
    package deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of aliases for docker hub. For images that we determine are to/from docker because they do not contain a registry hostname, jib uses the hostname: `registry-1.docker.io`

Code: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/jib/api/ImageReference.java#L38

Maybe using that in your maven settings could help?